# I am able to connect to Oracle Db using Toad but connection using sqlplus is not working. Getting TNS timeout error

Tags: oracle, database-connection, connection-string, sqlplus, tnsping

I am able to connect to Oracle DB using Toad with Datasource name and username/password. Oracle client 12 as Oracle driver. oracle database path is set properly in the environment variables. sqlnet.ora, listener.ora and tnsnames.ora is present in `ORACLE\ORANT\NETWORK\ADMIN` folder and configured properly.  I tried to query using Sqlplus in cmd prompt using following command:

```
 connect User/pass@dw-prod.server.int:1527/pdw1s_servicename
```

I am getting ORA-12170: TNS Connect timeout error. Please help.

Comment: We can't see how your data source is configured, but the error suggests you're using a different hostname or port number; or possibly that you're using two different (real or virtual) machines with network differences. (Your SQL\*Plus connection, at least, isn't using a TNS alias so tnsnames.ora etc. isn't really relevant.)

Comment: If you have properly configured the tnsnames.ora file on your machine then you can use the command: `connect user/password@tns_alias`. Also before that check, if you are able to connect using tns_alias by executing the command: `tnsping <tns_alias>`

Comment: Now i am able to connect to database using ezconnect. Now  how to use this information for Oracle ODBC driver configuration to create a connection string. Because TNS is not working properly in my system

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL*Plus, just need to connect using the TNS alias.

connect user/password@tns_alias

Comment: Now i am able to connect to database using ezconnect. Now how to use this information for Oracle ODBC driver configuration to create a connection string. Because TNS is not working properly in my system

Answer (score 0):

If your password contains specific characters like @ or ! probably you are getting the error for this